# Angular - the best approach to keep variables in a project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering what's the best approach to keep variables in Angular project.

I have an example, let's suppose I have a component which includes many variables, but I don't like that it makes my component so long and less transparent.

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-ballance',
    templateUrl: './balance.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./balance.component.scss']
})
export class BalanceComponent implements OnInit {


    list = [];
    list3 = [];
    errorMsg;
    numbOfElem = 0;
    numbOfElem2 = 0;
    items: Array<any>;
    items2: Array<any>;
    pageOfItems: Array<any>;
    pageOfItems2: Array<any>;
    clickData = false;
    datas: any;
    correctBalance = false;
    wrongBalance = false;
    extraBalance  = false;
    administrator = false;
    doubleBalance = true;
    individualBalance  = false;
    groupBallance = false;
    verifiedBallance = true;
    blockedBallance = false;
    deletedBallance = false;
    unverifiedBallance = false;
    prepaidBallance = false;
...
    ballanceSelect: any[] = [{
        label: 'xxx',
        name: this.showName,
        inputName: 'showName',
        status: this.showName.status,
    }, {
        label: 'xxx',
        name: this.showEmail,
        inputName: 'showEmail',
        status: this.showEmail.status,
    }, {
        label: 'xxx',
        name: this.showMobilePhone,
        inputName: 'showMobilePhone',
        status: this.showMobilePhone.status,
    }, 
    ];
...
```

My code is working but it doesn't look beautiful, is there some way to create extra file which would store my variables, objects, arrays etc and  how to connect that with component?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class in a seperate file to hold your data.

```
export class BalanceData{
correctBalance = false;
wrongBalance = false;
extraBalance  = false;
administrator = false;
doubleBalance = true;
individualBalance  = false;
groupBallance = false;
verifiedBallance = true;
blockedBallance = false;
deletedBallance = false;
unverifiedBallance = false;
prepaidBallance = false;
}
```

You'll need to import the seperate file

```
import { BalanceData} from '../balanceData.ts';
```

Then instead of declaring all your variables create an instance of your class.

```
data:BalanceData;
```

Then access the variables like this.

```
data.correctBalance
```

Answer (score 1):

Segregate your variables in category like class variable and local as per scope. We use the model classes in languages like C#, JAVA etc. You can also follow the same practice here as well. create a new class for class level variables and export it.
It will help you to maintain it and reuse it using inheritance/aggregation in some other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service with your settings variables, also you could create a class to create your data maybe. That way you dont pollute the controller. Then group like/similar variables in an object so the are nice and readable.

Something like this will reduce your vars

PS this is a rough idea of what you could do. I am pointing ideas not exact code to do

```
  componentData = [];

    createList(): void { // could put this in a service
        const data = {
            list: [],
            items: [],  
            pageOfItems: []
        }
        this.componentData.push(data);
    }

    createList(); // make as many as you want

    componentData[id].list; // access like this instead of list3
```